# How to get started with new PayPal development site

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to integrate PayPal for the first time in my life in an MVC 4 store. I am finding it really hard to grab some of the core concepts as PayPal's documentation seems to be way outdated and their latest developer site is different from their documentation. I will try to break down my questions into simple bullets so that someone could guide me. These are all related to one thing that I want to do, use PayPal in my site, never realized it will be so confusing!

- I have an existing personal account with PayPal, can I use sandbox
  site if I do not have a PayPal account? My current assumption is that
  I Cannot.
- When I create testing accounts on dev site, I use dummy addresses
  like buyer123@gmail.com etc. Although it notifies me that account has
  been created, I do not see that account in the list, do I need to
  enter valid email accounts for testing also?
- Currently I am residing outside US but when I create testing
  accounts, I leave them to the default value with country US. Is it ok
  or does it need to be valid as per my paypal account?
- Finally as I cannot see the newly created accounts I also cannot
  login to the sandbox site with their credentials, Kindly tell me what
  am I missing.

I apologize for multiple things but actually these are all related to getting started with PayPal development and after reading through their documentation and other help that is around, it seems there is some missing information. If anyone can please share screen shots, it would be ideal!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You need to have a LIVE PayPal account to login to developer.paypal.com and create Sandbox accounts.
  Alternatively, you can just go to https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/ to create Sandbox accounts for testing.
- You can enter any dummy email address to create Sandbox accounts, doesn't need to be a real one.
  You should be able to see those here.[image] As you can see the above ones are unreal email address I created for Sandbox testing.
- Yes, it is okay to create US accounts for testing purpose.
- If you are not able to login to https://www.sandbox.paypal.com you could try to reset the password from here(but am not sure why you are not able to see the recently created Sandbox accounts as you mentioned)[image: screenshot]
  [image: screenshot_change password]

If you are still facing issues, please contact www.papyal.com/mts and raise a support ticket.

Comment: Thanks Vimal, I was doing the exact same steps but due to some problem my users were not getting created. Now I have cleared all the browser cache and history and it seems to work. Probably was a glitch. Thanks for sharing the screen shots.